# Java - Russian strings and JTextField, changing the String to "????..."

Tags: java, swing, encoding, jtextfield

I'm writing a small application that should receive some English and Russian text from the user, then do some processing on it. I would prefer to keep both as on String, if possible.

The way I was trying to do it right now involved having a GUI I wrote using the swing lib, specifically the JTextField.

For the English strings, that works fine and all. However, the russian Strings keep coming out as "???????". I feel like I'm doing something wrong with the encodings, but I could not find for the life of me any resources about what I should do differently.

Here is the code:

```
JLabel name_ru;
JTextField name_russian;

public Gui()
{
    name_ru = new JLabel("Name in Russian:");
    name_russian = new JTextField();
}

public void run()
{
ru_name = name_russian.getText();
System.out.println(ru_name);
}
```

Upon actually adding my JTextField to my JFrame based GUI, I am able to prompt the printing of the JTextField.getText() String to consol and save it to a txt file using a BufferedWriter. If the text in the JTextField is in English, I have no porblem doing this. However , as soon as I try it with Russian text (Or any non-english text) my output comes out as "??????????". The way the text gets into that JTextField is simpley the user typing it in once the GUI is running.

I've looked around, however none of the solutions posted on here (or anywhere else where I could find) seemed to be dealing with the JTextField class - it seems that the .getText() returns a badly encoded string... Is there a way to change it? Help!

Thank you,
Eric.

Comment: Is the problem in the file that's saved, or your output "to consol"? Your question isn't clear at the moment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got my answer - the problem was with BOTH the consol output and the file output. The file I was outputting was a test, since I suspected I'm missing some eclipse setting to allow printing out UTF-8. Both answers helped me out to fix the issues.

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please try to be more specific. We didn't have any of your code, and only the vaguest of descriptions of the problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list to help you to write a better question next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println(ru_name);
```

will not be able to print the UTF-8(russian) characters with default console settings. And hence it is printing ??? for the characters. Make sure the console you use to display the output is encoded in UTF-8. If you are using eclipse then go to

`Run Configuration > Common -> Encoding` and select UTF-8 form the drop-down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for! I can't believe it's so obviouse, yet took me so long to find... One other question - how do I make sure that the String actually stays in this encoding once I compile and make a runnable JAR out of it? Or does that by default stays UTF-8? (I believe I read somewhere that it does...)

Comment: @Eric String reference will hold the UTF-8 characters properly, you just need to make sure that where you are printing the string is UTF-8 enabled. For example i mentioned for console, you need to make sure for files also as mentioned by Jon in his answer.

Comment: @ Juned Ahsan, Thanks, that's what I was hoping to hear!

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly *not* a program with Swing. `getText()` will return a normal Java String, which is *always* a sequence of UTF-16 code units.

> and save it to a txt file using a BufferedWriter

This is probably the problem. My guess is that you're using `FileWriter`, or just `OutputStreamWriter` with the platform-default encoding.

You should use an `OutputStreamWriter` (wrapping a `FileOutputStream`) but specify the encoding - ideally UTF-8. UTF-8 can represent all characters in Unicode.

You haven't said where you're *viewing* the output - you're just saying it "comes out as". If you're using Notepad or something similar to view the file, you may need to specify the encoding there, too.

Comment: Thanks, that helped the other part of my question! Writing out was just a thing I tried since I suspected that the consoul is to blame. Trying it with your method, combined with the answer above, I managed to write it out to a file as well. Thanks! :)